# Convert string separated values to array of objects

Tags: php

I have string separated values and I am trying to reformat them in a specific format.

```
$ids = $_REQUEST('ids'); // ids is comma separated string
// ids looks like abc@gmail.com,def@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com
```

For Google calendar api, I want it in this format:

```
array(
        array('email' => 'abc@gmail.com'),
        array('email' => 'def@gmail.com'),
        array('email' => 'xyz@gmail.com'),

    )
```

Comment: Please post the code you already have and any errors you might get. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Please always check if there are already similar questions in the community

Answer (score 2):

The requirement is quite simple:

1. Explode the string by comma.
2. Get Email addresses
3. Append them to array by adding `email` as a key.
4. Done.

You can do it with PHP's [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function:

```
<?php
$emailStr= "abc@gmail.com,def@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com";
$emails = explode(',', $emailStr);
//echo '<pre>';print_r($emails);echo '</pre>';
$gmails = [];
if (! empty($emails)) {
    foreach ($emails as $email) {
        $gmails[] = ['email' => $email];
    }
}

echo '<pre>';print_r($gmails);echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => abc@gmail.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => def@gmail.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [email] => xyz@gmail.com
        )

)
```